# Best way to combine offline map (e.g. Open Street Maps) with Google Maps for iOS?

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

We have implemented Google Maps in an app for tourists but we want to provide seamless offline maps. We can generate these from the OSM data and we can even display these on the Google Maps with a negative zIndex which means they generally only show when the online map tiles are not available. However there are some issues with this approach:

1/ After going offline, for a while, Google Maps shows a very poor version of it's map (i.e. if you zoom in it is very blurry).

2/ As user moves around the map, sometimes the cached tiles (poor quality usually) show up and disappear.

3/ We can't control the zoom level when offline and so sometimes our map tiles won't be shown if the user zooms too much.

Ideally we'd like to be able to know if google maps can't load a tile so we could display our own. Is this possible? Or can we fix the above issues?

Comment: Why Google at all if you already have OSM? I also fear that this is a gray area from Google side

Comment: @Karussell Because we have standardised on Google across 4 different platforms and we only need the offline mapping for mobile clients. OSM also doesn't look as good as Google Maps in our experience.

Comment: You can't use google maps offline, usually OSM is the only viable alternative. Google API is not very well controllable programmatically, so I would use some other API to have best user experience with offline features. I know some apps are using two APIs: google when user is online, and Nutiteq (developer.nutiteq.com) with OSM offline when user needs offline maps. Disclosure: i'm developer of Nutiteq.